# The limit of a sequence of $\ell^p$ is the limit of each components?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $1 \leq p < \infty$ be a real number

Let $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \ell^p$ be a sequence of $\ell^p$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$

Let $v_{n,m}$ be the $m$-th element in the $n$-th sequence $v_n$

If
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}:
\lim_{n \to \infty}
v_{n,m}
=
w_m
$$
and 
$$
\left\|
w
\right\|_p
< \infty
$$
is it true that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
v_n
=w 
\text{ (in $\ell^p$ metric) }
$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this does not hold. You can define $v_n \in\ell^p$ such that
$$v_{n,m} = \delta_{nm} = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 &&\text{if }n=m \\
0&&\text{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} v_{n,m} =0,$$
but
$$||v_n-\textbf{0}||_p = 1$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: thanks @Yannik for your answer